# How to jQuery.post() with no data to send

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this the correct way but I'm trying to send a small amount of data to the server and receive a couple of strings back.  Because of the way the server CMS works the data is most easily sent in the URL path so I have no need to send any additional 'data'.  For example :

```
      var url = '/footnotes/cleartile/'+nid+'/'+tid+'/'+side;
      var mydata = 'This serves no purpose';
      jQuery.post(url, mydata, function(data) {
        console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
      });
```

Is jQuery.post() the correct mechanism for this type of communication ?  And if so, what should I pass in the data parameter when nothing is necessary ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To keep the same function I would use this:

```
var url = '/footnotes/cleartile/'+nid+'/'+tid+'/'+side;
jQuery.post(url, {} , function(data) {
   // The data here represents the answer from the server
   console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

or

```
jQuery.post(url, function(data) {
   // The data here represents the answer from the server
   console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer solve my issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

[`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) doesn't require the `data` argument at all, it's listed as optional. You can just leave it out:

```
var url = '/footnotes/cleartile/'+nid+'/'+tid+'/'+side;
jQuery.post(url, function(data) {
    console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `jQuery.get` in this case (if the server does accept a `GET` rather than only a `POST`, which is most certainly the case here).

Comment: GET can be cached, whereas POST will not be cached.  Sometimes this matters (server load vs. always getting fresh data).

Comment: Even if what Paul said weren't true, if the server-side state is changed by the operation, it should be a POST, not a GET. GET is meant to be idempotent.